# why f(M) is sub manifold

Tags: manifolds

Let  map  **f** of **M** into **N**  be an injective immersion. show taht if  **M** is compact then **f(M)** is submanifold of  **N**.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where do you know/suppose the compactness assumption will be important?

Answer (score 0):

Provided **f** is an injective continuous mapping, we can know that **f** is a topological embedding from the fact that **M** is compact and **N** is a Hausdorff space. Then, **f** is a constant-rank embedding, which shows that **f(M)** is exactly a submanifold of **N** by Constant Rank Theorem.